# how to draw a gaussian curve using canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I tried using `BeiziercurveTo`, but I couldn't draw the perfect gaussian curve.

[image: gaussian curve sample picture]

Is there any optimal way of doing, aside from finding out all the points using the gaussian equation and joining them?

[image: formula]

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [**BeiziercurveTo**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp). it will be clearly Explained in W3 schools. give a look.

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(20,100,200,100,200,20);
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: i tried using this,but i need a perfect gaussian curve